# gRPC C# Specifying the namespace for the generated .cs files

Tags: c#, namespaces, grpc, grpc-c#

I've followed the gRPC C# tutorial to generate and use .cs files using a source .proto file. The tutorial example gives a namespace to the .cs files, but when I try for my .proto file, there is NO namespace being applied whatsoever. The .proto file is **externally controlled**, so I have **no control** over the contents. Also, there are NO 'options' in the .proto for 'csharp-namespace'.

I'm using the (Visual Studio / NuGet + Build) method to generate these files. How do I specify a namespace for these objects?

For reference, I'm using this [.proto file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alttpo/sni/main/protos/sni/sni.proto). As you can see, the generically-named 'Devices' service is causing some name conflicts in my project. It would seem odd to me that as a gRPC-client-developer, as in the one building a client to wrap a service, that you don't have control over its namespace.

Comment: No, I specifically mentioned that I do not have control over the .proto file's contents. It changes every time they make an update to it. Unless there is some kind of automated transformation that could be applied to it during the Build process, but I'm unaware of such ability.

Comment: It seems you just can't do it: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/6846

Comment: Can't you modify the .proto file before passing it to protoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial

> In C#, your generated classes will be placed in a namespace matching
> the package name if csharp_namespace is not specified. In our example,
> the csharp_namespace option has been specified to override the
> default, so the generated code uses a namespace of
> Google.Protobuf.Examples.AddressBook instead of Tutorial.

option csharp_namespace = "Google.Protobuf.Examples.AddressBook";

Did you try passing this option to protoc ?

> It would seem odd to me that ... you don't have control over
> its namespace.

There are 3 options available for you.

1. Easiest which you already know (but don't want to do?) just manually update the file in place. Done!
2. If its a one time thing, and for whatever reason you don't want to modify the proto file, download the code generator [from here](http://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases) and run protoc against those proto files which will generate C# classes similar to what Visual Studio Build is doing. You can then include the generated C# files in your solution. You must now leave out the proto file from your project OR set its Build Action to None if you do include it.
3. If there are a lot of proto files and they will be changing frequently, you need to enhance step (2). You would want c# files generated as part of your `MSBuild`. You can do fancy (or really overengineer) things here like host the protos in a package externally, and MSBuild will download it during build. This step would need to happed before you can open your project in IDE else it will complain about missing C# files. n.b. these auto generated files will be part of project but not checked in to your source control. Your CI process will follow the same MSBuild process and generate files before it builds solution.

You get the idea. Basically you have a lot of options and control over the namspacing. Just not one that work out of the box.

Comment: I don't know what protoc is. I'm pressing the Build Solution button inside Visual Studio.

Comment: You can [download the code generator from here](http://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases) and run protoc against those "external" proto files which will generate C# classes similar to what Visual Studio Build is doing. You can then include the generated C# files in your solution. You must then leave out the proto file from your project OR set its Build Action to None if you do include it.

Comment: @codemann8 Protoc is the [protobuf compiler](https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/). Whenever you build the solution inside Visual Studio, protoc [generates C# code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp-generated) from the proto files. Like CodeReaper said, these generated files are physical files in your build output, which can be modified (f.e. the namespace can be changed). Just make sure once you modified them to not overwrite them again with the next time you press build.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve me manually editing something every time a new update to the .proto file happens. If there is some ability to add a script to the Build process that can transform the proto file or can intervene the underlying protoc process that seems to occur during the Build process. I'd be interested in that, but I'm not sure what's possible within Visual Studio.

Comment: "_doesn't involve me manually editing something every time a new update to the .proto file happen_" are you expecting that when an external party publishes an update to proto files, then, the c# file sitting in your dev machine is automatically updated? We don't even have that for swagger files yet. You need to set up a custom MSBuild process. [Get started here at MSBuild Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022) You can even add a step that gets the latest proto file over the internet during build. If you are after a quick one line fix, there isn't one.

Comment: Yes, I already have a process that automatically pulls in the latest proto file (being that it comes packaged in a utility that I have installed and it has automatic updates), then I add the "Link" to it in my project where it pulls it from that spot. I definitely didn't expect it to be a quick one-liner fix given how gRPC was designed, which doesn't seem like good design imo. But yeah, I'll have to look into how to set up MSBuild to do this.