# How to set a global C# namespace for Protobuf files without modifying each file

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm working on a project that involves integrating with a third-party API using Protobuf. The provided `.proto` files do not specify a C# namespace using `option csharp_namespace = "Example"`, leading to less desirable default namespaces (e.g. `using UserAttribute2;`). With thousands of `.proto` files, manually updating each file whenever there's a new API version is impractical. I'm seeking a way to globally set a C# namespace for these files without directly editing them.

```
// User attributes messages

syntax = "proto2";

package user_attribute_2;

// User defined attribute.
message UserAttribute
{
  // Attribute name.
  required string name = 1;

  // Attribute value (optional for modification if attribute is deleted).
  optional string value = 2;

  // True if attribute has to be deleted during modify operation.
  optional bool deleted = 3;
}

// Modification of order's user attributes.
message ModifyUserAttributes
{
  // ID of the order chain.
  required string chain_order_id = 1;

  // ID of the order's account.
  required sint32 account_id = 2;

  // List of attributes to modify.
  // See Order.user_attribute for additional description.
  repeated UserAttribute user_attributes = 3;

  // Flag used by the client for marking the user attributes checked/unchecked.
  // Empty means to leave the flag the same as it was.
  optional bool is_checked = 4;
}
```

### .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.25.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.60.0">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="WebAPI\**\*.proto" />
    <Protobuf Include="common\**\*.proto" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

I attempted to set a global namespace using the `AdditionalProtocArguments` property:

```
<Protobuf Include="WebAPI\**\*.proto" AdditionalProtocArguments="--csharp_opt=base_namespace=Example" />
```

However, this resulted in an error:

> Namespace Example is not a prefix namespace of base namespace

This error is understandable as my package declarations don't match the `Example` namespace (`package Example;`) (similar issue described [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/29953)).

I'm looking for a way to achieve this without altering the original .proto files, as they are provided by a third party. Is there a known workaround or a solution to specify a global C# namespace in such a scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gRPC C# Specifying the namespace for the generated .cs files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396762/grpc-c-sharp-specifying-the-namespace-for-the-generated-cs-files)

Comment: @fredrik not really.

Comment: Can you use `--csharp_opt` with `base_namespace` (see [C#-specific options](https://protobuf.dev/reference/csharp/csharp-generated/#compiler_options))?

Comment: @DazWilkin, this is what I attempted but resulted into `Namespace Example is not a prefix namespace of base namespace` because `package cqg;` != `package Example;`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in your question. I think we may be out of options (see [Issues](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues?q=is%3Aissue+--csharp_opt+base_namespace)). It's been awhile since I wrote C#. Is there any concept in C# that contains namespaces? In Rust, crates can be used and in Go, modules provide a mechanism by which generated namespaces can be kept distinct. Could you do something similar in C#?

Comment: There isn't a command line option or Grpc.Tools option to specify the C# namespace. Your only option is to edit the files - maybe add a script to do this when you copy the files into your source.